# How to differentiate value with existing value via hook in SugarCRM?

Tags: sugarcrm

I am attempting to use an `after_save` logic hook to if i am update assignee in Leads then same assignee should be assigned to its related Notes. Below is the code I am using. I am currently on 6.5 enterprise. Does anyone have an idea of how i can compare both values?

In modules/Leads/logic_hook.php

```
$hook_array['after_save'] = Array();
$hook_array['after_save'][] = Array(1, 'Leads edited', 'custom/modules/Leads/ExtraLogic.php', 'ExtraLogic', 'saveAssigneeToNotes');
```

In custom/modules/Leads/ExtraLogic.php

```
    //check if a fields value has changed
    if ($assigned_user_id != $bean->assigned_user_id)
    {
        // execute logic
    } else {
        // Same value
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, it would be easier to simply use a `before_save` logic hook. I would recommend reviewing the different use cases in the official documentation: [Module Hooks](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Module_Framework/Logic_Hooks/Module_Hooks/index.html).

Here's how I would update the Notes' Assigned User when the related Lead's Assigned User changes:

In `custom/modules/Leads/logic_hooks.php` include this entry,

```
<?php
$hook_version = 1;
$hook_array = array();
$hook_array['before_save'] = array();
$hook_array['before_save'][] = array(
  50,
  'Update Assigned User for Notes',
  'custom/modules/Leads/NotesUpdater.php',
  'NotesUpdater',
  'updateOnAssignedUserChange',
);
```

That file sets the reference to the file, class and method to invoke. Now create `custom/modules/Leads/NotesUpdater.php` with the following content,

```
<?php
class NotesUpdater

/**
 * @param $bean Lead
 * @param $event string e.g. 'before_save'
 * @param $arguments array
 */
public function updateOnAssignedUserChange($bean, $event, $arguments){
  // skip if this is a new record, since there are no related Notes yet
  if(empty($bean->fetched_row)) return TRUE;

  // check for a change on the Assigned User on the Lead
  if($bean->assigned_user_id != $bean->fetched_row['assigned_user_id]){
    $bean->load_relationship('notes');
    foreach($bean->notes->getBeans() as $note){
        $note->assigned_user_id = $bean->assigned_user_id;
        // if the Note record was changed, save it
        // (otherwise there is no need to save)
        if($note->assigned_user_id != $note->fetched_row['assigned_user_id']){
          $note->save();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This method of detecting the change and acting on it can be done 100% by the above `before_save` logic hook. IMO use of the `after_save` hook is rare and very specific, but should you need it in the future, the SugarCRM's Developer Blog entry [Doing before/after field comparisons in after_save logic hooks](https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2013/08/21/doing-beforeafter-field-comparisons-in-after_save-logic-hooks/) describes how to do so.

Comment: I want to use `after_save` because assignee should be updated from `Leads` and then i want to match with old assignee for same lead record. If assignee same for lead then i don't want to call code about `notes` which is given by you.

Comment: I believe I understand the issue entirely. I've expanded the answer to demonstrate the entire file entries that will provide this, the logic hook definition and entire class and method file. All of this is done within the `before_save`, the `after_save` method is not required. It provides little value over `before_save` and it's use case is rare IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to compare any values (at least not in SugarCRM 7, not sure about 6.5), because SugarCRM already did that for you:

Hooks are usually called with these args: (`$bean, $event, $arguments`).

In `after_save` hooks, `$arguments` will look something like this when changing the assigned user:

```
Array
(
    [isUpdate] => 1
    [dataChanges] => Array
        (
            [date_modified] => Array
                (
                    [field_name] => date_modified
                    [data_type] => datetime
                    [before] => 2016-12-28 22:05:50
                    [after] => 2017-02-21 19:23:42
                )

            [modified_by_name] => Array
                (
                    [field_name] => modified_by_name
                    [data_type] => relate
                    [before] => Administrator
                    [after] => admin
                )

            [assigned_user_id] => Array
                (
                    [field_name] => assigned_user_id
                    [data_type] => id
                    [before] => d4229698-640b-18f9-af63-179b140cfa7a
                    [after] => a4329698-640b-18f9-af63-179b140cfe76
                )

        )

)
```

(Code generated by putting `file_put_contents('/tmp/after_save_arguments.txt', print_r($arguments, true));` in an `after_safe` hook)

So all the info you need should already be in there.

You could just check for `array_key_exists('assigned_user_id', $arguments['dataChanges'])` and use the `$bean`'s current variables to do some logic on the new value.
If you also need to do logic concerning the *old* value, there's `$arguments['dataChanges']['assigned_user_id']['before']` for you to use.

Oh right, also don't forget to check if `isUpdate == false`, because in that case the bean has just been newly created and `dataChanges` will be empty as the record didn't exist before.
In such case you're only interested in the current values of the `$bean` anyway.